# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory [opening spreadsheets from my computer in google colab]

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I am trying to open a spreadsheet from my computer in google colab, this error is returning.

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/common.py in get_handle(path_or_buf, mode, encoding, compressio
n, memory_map, is_text, errors, storage_options)
    709         else:
    710             # Binary mode
--> 711             handle = open(handle, ioargs.mode)
    712         handles.append(handle)
    713 

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
```

Does the spreadsheet have to be in a specific directory?
Can it be on my desktop? How should I copy its address?

Comment: you cannot open a file from your computer. Please upload it in colab or in your drive. If you upload it in your drive then you can connect your drive with colab and access the spreadsheet. To upload you can just drag and drop in the content folder `(Files)` within colab.

Comment: Make sure the path you are giving is correct, and provide stuff you have tried.

Comment: You can also use `from google.colab import files 
dataset_file_dict = files.upload()` to upload the file in colab manually from your device. Just execute one cell

Comment: To access the file you uploaded `test_file = open('/content/your_file.txt', "r")`

Comment: To connect your google drive: `from google.colab import drive 
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')` and then to access one file from drive: `text_file = "/content/gdrive/MyDrive/folderName/your-file.txt"`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!!

I've tried

```
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')

from google.colab import files
dataset_file_dict = files.upload()
```

and then a "search" window appeared, so I could search my file directly on my desktop.

thank you so much!